# select string array values based on another array

Tags: julia

I can select data that is equal to a value with

```
data = rand(1:3, 10)
value = 2
data .== value
```

or equal to a list of values with

```
values = [1, 2]
in.(data, (values,))
```

The last one is generic and also works for a scalar: `in.(data, (value, ))` .

However, this works for `Int`, but the generic does not work for `String` values:

```
data = rand(["A", "B", "C"], 10)
value = "B"
data .== value
values = ["A","B"]
in.(data, (values, ))
in.(data, (value, ))
ERROR: use occursin(x, y) for string containment
```

Is there a generic way for `String`s?

For a generic `val` input I'm now writing the following, but I feel there must be a better solution.

```
isa(val, AbstractArray) ? in.(data, (val,)) : data .== val
```

Background: I'm creating a function to select rows from a dataframe (and do something with them) but I want to allow for both a list of values as well as a single value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a trick that is worth knowing:

```
[x;]
```

Now - if `x` is an array it will remain an array. If `x` is a scalar it will become a 1-element array. And this is exactly what you need.

So you can write

```
in.(data, ([val;],))
```

The drawback is that it allocates a new array, but I guess that `val` is small and it is not used in performance critical code? If the code is performance critical I think it is better to treat scalars and arrays by separate branches.